# Using Spotify API to know how many times an artist is played

Tags: api, spotify, cocoalibspotify-2.0, libspotify

Can you use the Spotify API to know how many times an artist is played each hour or day?

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately that data is not published. I agree that this would be really, really cool, though.